# Azure KeyVault configuration sharing

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

Recently I've started using the azure KeyVault with asp net core web app and found that all the new projects that have the keyVault integrated are rather hard to setup locally since the secrets.json file contains nothing.
It's fine when you have the stuff ready, but for new developers, we need to share the file manually. Wonder if there is any better way of doing this without committing the file repository, which would be bad since we want to protect the secret stuff...
Anyone experiences a similar scenario and maybe could advise how to set things up properly so new devs would not have the headache to think about where to get the missing configurations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear (sorry can't comment yet) as you ask about Azure Key Vault, but next it comes out it's about Secret Manager and json files with secret data.

Azure Key Vault is a web service on azure platform, so to use it during developement you just need to be logged to azure on your local environment. It can be done through Visual Studio or Azure CLI. Your azure account also has to have access to that Key Vault.

Regarding Secret Manager and automation in sharing files with a team, It could be done by creating a small CLI tool which will be run as after build action and it will download file/fetch secrets from some API and creating a json file on a proper location. Of course authentication options of this tool will be a thing to consider. If you're using a VPN you can use a network hard drive as a repository, but security of this solution is rather low.